# NHibernate one-to-many relationship without bidirectional association

Tags: nhibernate

Is my understanding correct, that the following class and table design is not possible in NHibernate:

```
public class Parent
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   public virtual ISet<Child> Children { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class Child
{
   public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
   ...
}

table Parent { Id, ... }
table Child { Id, ParentId (not null), ... }
```

So notice the following:

- a one-to-many association between parent and child
- using an ISet
- no bidirectional association from Child back to Parent
- Child's ParentId column is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My knee jerk reaction was to say that that it was supported but I think you are right. Your options are either - bidirectional relationship or nullable ParentId column in Child table.

Here's a interesting thread where Ayende gets into it in the bug tracker for NH <strike>http://nhjira.koah.net/browse/NH-1050</strike> (it's the previous release of NH but I think the answer is the same)

**UPDATE 5/7/11**

Seems like something weird is going on with the Nhibernate JIRA (I.e. no domain name). The link can currently be found at https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1050. However with NHibernate 3 out in the wild I have not checked to see if this question is still an issue.

Comment: The link above (to Ayende article) appears to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is very much intended by and supported by NHibernate.

Comment: How can I do this - according to the docs:
"If the <key>  column of a <one-to-many> association is declared NOT NULL, NHibernate may cause constraint violations when it creates or updates the association. To prevent this problem, you must use a bidirectional association with the many valued end (the set or bag) marked as inverse="true"."

Comment: So try using `<set inverse="true" />` in the mapping for the parent's collection-of-children.

Comment: But its one of my requirements that I don't want a bi-directional association, because it makes the model more confusing.